# change column names with same name in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `mydf` with n number of columns with same column name say `name`. I want to change them to `name1 name2 and name3 ..name-nth` columns. How do I do that in R?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cols <- which(names(mydf == 'name'))
names(mydf)[cols] <- paste0('name', seq_along(cols))
```

The first line finds the indices of the columns with name 'name'.
The second assigns new names.

Comment: The code should be `cols <- which(names(mydf) == 'name')`, shouldn't it? (one closing bracket is in the wrong place I think.

Answer (score 4):

```
cols <- names(dat) == "name"
names(dat)[cols] <- paste0("name", seq.int(sum(cols)))
```