# List of dataframes containing columns with the same name

Tags: r, dataframe

After converting some JSON data I have a list of dataframes. Several of the dataframes include columns with the same name:

```
str(json)
List of 2
$ :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  2 variables:
..$ a                    :Factor
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "a"
..$ b                    :Factor
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "b"
$ :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  3 variables:
..$ a                    :Factor
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "a"
..$ b                    :Factor
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "b"
..$ b
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "b"
```

Whose values are:

```
json[[1]]                    json[[2]]
a    b                       a     b     b
car  boat                    bus   plane  train
```

I have tried to convert the whole list in a unique dataframe using:

```
 data <- rbind.fill(json)
```

But then only the first of the columns sharing name is considered:

```
data
     a    b
1   car  boat
2   bus plane
```

I would like to obtain a dataframe like this:

```
data
    a    b
1  car  boat
2  bus  plane,train
```

How could I merge the columns like that?

I have not been able to reproduce in practice a minimal example as R does not allow me to create two columns with the same name (as shown in the answer by Shorpy) and my actual list includes hundreds of columns. However, I think dput output could be reduced to something like this:

```
dput(json)
list(structure(list(`a` = structure(1L, .Names = "a", .Label = "car", class = "factor"), 
    `b` = structure(1L, .Names = "b", .Label = "boat", class = "factor") , .Names = c("a","b"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"),
 structure(list(`a` = structure(1L, .Names = "a", .Label = "bus", class = "factor"),
    `b` = structure(1L, .Names = "b", .Label = "plane", class = "factor"),
    `b` = structure(1L, .Names = "b", .Label = "train", class = "factor"), .Names = c("a","b","b"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"))
```

I have tried to distinguish the columns by changing their names as explained in this other question: [change column names with same name in dataframe in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420790/change-column-names-with-same-name-in-dataframe-in-r). However,several names may be repeated in the same dataframe and repeated names are not the same in different dataframes, which makes it more complicate.

Comment: Can you paste into your question the output of `dput(json)`. That will preserve the exact structure of your data and make it easy for us to paste it into our R sessions.

Comment: @eipi10 I have just modified my question.

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like this:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
l <- list()
l[[1]] <- data_frame(a = "car", b = "boat")
l[[2]] <- data_frame(a = "car", b = "plane", b = "train")


recode <- function(df){

  copies <- df[, names(df) == "b"]
  out <- data_frame(a = df$a,
                    b = reduce(copies, paste))
  out
}

map_df(l, recode)
```

Comment: I think your answer is on the right track but I have some trouble to make it work.  Could it be adapted to make it valid for a general case where `b` is unknown and there could be more than one repeated column name?